Calculate integral involving a delta distribution
I'm trying to calculate the following integral:
$$
\int_{-x_1=L/2}^{L/2}
\int_{-x_2=L/2}^{L/2}
\int_{p_1=-\infty}^{\infty}
\int_{p_2=-\infty}^{\infty}
\delta\left(\frac{p_{1}^{2} + p_{2}^{2}}{2}
 +\frac{1}{2}\,\omega\,\left[x_{1} - x_{2}\right]^{2} -E\right){\rm d}p_{1}\, {\rm d}p_{2}\,{\rm d}x_{1}\,{\rm d}x_{2}
$$
where $E > 0$ and $\omega > 0$.

I think, if I'm not mistaken, it is ( isn't it ? ) possible to write it as:
$$\int_{\Sigma} \frac{d
   \sigma}{|\nabla(g(p_1,p_2,x_1,x_2)|}=\int_{\Sigma}\frac{d
   \sigma}{\sqrt{p_1^2+p_2^2+2\omega^2(x_1-x_2)^2}}
$$
However, I'm not able to find a suitable parametrization of the hypersurface described by the equation
$$
E = 
\frac{p_{1}^{2} + p_{2}^{2}}{2} +
\frac{1}{2}\,\omega\,
\left(x_{1} - x_{2}\right)^{2}
$$

The question arises from Statistical Mechanics. Any help ?.

"Statistical Mechanics" what? You should specify the author and perhaps more information to locate the reference. Editor, year...

Physically speaking, I want to describe two point particles in 1D interacting via an harmonic potential and I want to calculate the statistical weight in the microcanonical ensemble, so I need (x1-x2).

What makes you think that this is the correct integral for what you want to calculate?

Is there any calculation of the same quantity but for another situation that you can show?

Yes indeed! If we delete x1 and x2, and consider only p1 and p2, the integral is very easy to solve even for an infinite number of $\p_k$, in polar coordinates, it is treated in all standard textbook of statistical mechanics because in this way it is possible to calculate the entropy of perfect gas, and then the equation of state PV=NKT, for N$ \to \infty$, and N/V constant. Take for example Huang, Statistical Mechanics, 2edition, page 138.

However in that case we suppose that we are in a volume V, or in 1D in an interval of length L, and the integral in dx_1 and d_x2 gives L, as if the estremes of integration were -L/2 and L/2 for the x_1 and x_2.

I've introduced some corrections to the model.
